# Type renaming in C# with a renamed type

Tags: c#, .net

```
using IdType = System.Guid;
using RowType = System.Tuple<System.Guid, object>
```

works.
while

```
using IdType = System.Guid;
using RowType = System.Tuple<IdType, object>
```

does not compile.
The `IdType` declared at first row cannot be used with further `using` it seems.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? Seems like a good way to obfuscate your code!

Comment: @DavidG Down the road, the type used for the ID might change, I suppose.

Comment: @DavidG My code does (not) look like `System.Tuple<System.Func<object, bool>, object[]>`. I try to get away from it and my example was simplified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work:

```
using IdType = System.Guid;
namespace x
{
    using RowType = System.Tuple<IdType, object>;
}
```

The reason being that type aliases only apply within declarations in the namespace within which they are contained.

Answer (score 0):

```
using IdType = System.Guid;
using RowType = System.Tuple<System.Guid, object>;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public void Test()
{
  var guideq = typeof(IdType).Equals(typeof(System.Guid));
  var typeeq = typeof(RowType).Equals(typeof(System.Tuple<System.Guid,
  object>));
  System.Tuple<System.Guid, object> obj = new RowType(IdType.NewGuid(), "");
}
```

`IdType and System.Guid` is Same Type.

`System.Tuple<System.Guid, object>` and `RowType` is of the same type. In this
 situation it's just working as an alias name. So we need use any place.

In the code i am checking these two types for equality and that it is true; because it's alias name for the same type.

This type renaming (or) type alias name is helpful for coding, 
to understand and avoid confusion. Especially when types are getting complex.

Comment: Capital letters should be used sparingly - generally, at the start of sentences and for proper nouns. Not for every word (or every other word)